# Does varicocele size vary with room temperature?

Tags: testicles, varicose-veins

This doubt stems from a discussion I had a few days ago with a friend involving varicocele relief.

According to his guess, a prolonged sauna session would produce vasodilation at the level of the skin which would mean that a lower amount of blood would remain in inner organs including the testicles, reducing the size of the varicocele. I responded that this wouldn't work because testicles are detached enough from the body such that they would act in the opposite way (veins would vasodilate to best dissipate heat), and added that only a strong localized decrease in temperature consistent through the day could substantially decrease varicocele size.

However, none of us are experts in the subject by any means, so that's why i'm here.

Comment: This is a hypothesis (at the time of writing the article).  Calcification of varicoceles. BPH. Vitamin K2 to direct newly ingested calcium to the bones. There is already evidence I believe that over 400mg calcium a day increases the chance of prostate cancer. Perhaps directing calcium away from the blood vessels would help to prevent prostate cancer and reduce congestion in the area. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25613567/

Comment: I don’t know exactly what medical condition you are discussing, but it may progress to BPH.